# close webcam in openCV python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to close web cam i used the cap.released() but it does not close the web cam after it captures the image. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
     cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
     if cap.isOpened():
             ret, frame = cap.read()
             print(ret)
             print(frame)
     else:
         ret=False
     img1=  cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
     plt.imshow(img1)
     plt.title('Color Image RGB')
     plt.xticks([])
     plt.yticks([])
     plt.show()
     cap.release() 
if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: your main function is empty. You should fix this first

Comment: Please, make a proper [mcve] -- fix the indentation, and remove anything irrelevant (e.g. what does matplotlib have to do with the issue?) Also, how do you know it's not released, when `cap.release()` appears to be the last statement in your example?

Comment: my webcam light is still on

Comment: I can't see if statement. Also, check I code after else part is executing properly.

Comment: Please fix the code such that one can copy and paste it from the question and see the same result as you. Also state *how* you are running this code.

Comment: @MohammadArshad What version of OpenCV are you using? What platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cam will stay active until you close the figure, i.e. until the script finishes. This is because you only release the capture afterwards,

```
plt.show()
cap.release()
```

If you want to turn off the camera after taking the image, reverse this order

```
cap.release() 
plt.show()
```